# Understanding a line of example-code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, comet, long-polling

I'm trying to modify [this example](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2011/04/12/roll-your-own-mvc-3-long-polling-chat-site/) to my needs, but one line in particular has me stumped. The line `((Action<List<MessageInfo>>)parm)(msgs);` in the chatserver makes absolutely no sense to me. I can see that it typecasts (msgs) to the type `((Action<List<MessageInfo>>)parm);`, but it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

I hope that someone can help me understand this, as I have a feeling it one of the last pieces I'm missing of this puzzle...

Kind regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are casting a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), then invoking it with `msgs`.

This bit:

```
((Action<List<MessageInfo>>)parm);
```

Casts the delegate. Then it invokes the delegate with `msgs`.

Breaking it down a bit:

```
Action<List<MessageInfo>> del = ((Action<List<MessageInfo>>)parm);
del(msgs);
```

The author just chose to collapse all of that into one line.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. It's not easy being new when the old ones "cheats" in new ways ;)

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
((Action<List<MessageInfo>>)parm)(msgs)
```

is not a simple cast, it's a cast followed by an invocation of the method. Basically it does this:

```
Action<List<MessageInfo>> action = (Action<List<MessageInfo>>)parm;
action(msgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

What they are saying is:

Consider that:

`parm` is an `Action`

that takes as a parameter a `List` of `<MessageInfo>`s

and since `Action`s are executable, execute it,

passing `msgs` as a parameter.